# Animation Start and Exit in the same React component

Tags: reactjs, react-functional-component

I have a Menu component which contains two animations. Start and Exit. I click on the button in the Header, the component is rendered, and the fade-in function is triggered in useEffect .
Clicking again removes the component. The problem is that I have to store the start animation in the Menu component and the exit animation in the button component. It's inconvenient and confusing.
I would like to store both animations in Menu. To do this, you need to somehow call the Exit function in the child component from the parent.
I've been struggling with this for a very long time. I will be glad to any ideas.
The components are functional.
p.s. I am using the npm package for animations. So I just need to call the function for it to work

Comment: Did you tried using callback?

Comment: @upender I then have to write the animation logic in another component. I would like to call a function written in a Menu component

Comment: could you post your code here, so that it will be easy to understand your query